# WebApi for logging and e-mail purposes

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-web-api

I have and ASP.NET MVC 4 website that currently logs some specific information about user interactions and also send several e-mails to the Admin group reporting CRUD operations performed.

This is working as expected however I want to move this functionality to WebApi since in all this operations I don't need a result for the end user, and I thought that would speed up my website if the API would workout this for itself without blocking my website.

Is this possible ? Should WebApi be used for this ?

Yesterday I tried to move this to WebApi however my website still blocks waiting for WebApi response.

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it is entirely possible.

Look at One-way or Asynchronous operations to stop the blocking.

Comment: Thank you !! Yesterday I lost so many time trying to do it Async, however this One-Way call is specifically what I need : I had this code yesterday `var response = await client.PostAsJsonAsync("api/WAPIMail", model).ConfigureAwait(false);` so I just removed the `var response = await` and it worked just like I wanted it !! Cheers